# Is it possible to manage HTML elements without using DOM API?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm learning programming only a few months, and I'm wonder, is it possible to access and manipulate HTML/XML elements by javascript, but without DOM API ? 
For example to create your own API or something else?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: There is no reason to do this. Or even want to do this. I know that it can be interesting to think you might build something from scratch but... don't just don't it's not going to work.

Comment: I was just wondering if this is possible and if so, how to do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  One must use the browser API for accessing the DOM via javascript, so it's hard to imagine how you could access the DOM via javascript with that API.  You can't even get the raw HTML without getting a DOM element and using the `.innerHTML` property so there isn't really away to manipulate things without using the API.

You could build your own API on top of the existing API (which is sort of what frameworks like jQuery and YUI) do, but internally they would still be using the existing DOM API to access DOM elements.

Your question seems a little odd (how can you access the DOM without using the API for accessing the DOM) so I'm wondering if perhaps you could explain what problem you're really trying to solve?

There are a few manipulations that can be configured purely via CSS using the `:hover` state and you can even set up CSS3 animations in modern browsers using pure CSS, but that's about the extent of what can be manipulated without the javascript DOM API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm just in the process of learning JavaScript/DOM and etc., and I was just wondering the possibility of javascript...

Comment: @GiviKesanashvili - why would you want to change the DOM without using the DOM API?  We don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use strings, but this is undesirable. Mainly for a couple reasons. Manipulating the string for very large amounts of DOM can be a hassle. And it is more efficient (and best practice) to use document fragments as opposed to inserting the strings using `innerHTML`.

You could overwrite or extend to prototype for `HtmlElement` and then go about adding in your own functionality, but that is akin to reinventing the wheel. A lot of work would be put into basically using the same exact functionality available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you give me some examples or useful links, from where i can learn how to manipulate HTML as string?